# Login with Facebook - Ionicframework

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework, facebook-login

I have implemented Login with Facebook using

```
https://ccoenraets.github.io/ionic-tutorial/ionic-facebook-integration.html
```

I've added SiteUrl as **http://localhost:8100** in Facebook App Settings page.

It is working perfectly fine in browser when I use **ionic serve**
but when i build the APK and running on mobile it is saying

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more
>   of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match
>   the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of
>   one of the App's domains.

Where could the issue be? I really doubt how http://localhost:8100 works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that siteURL given is `localhost:8100`, which is the actual URL when you are running app in browser as it is running on `localhost:8100` but when you run app on mobile then your app is not running on `localhost:8100`. You need to add a separate URL for mobile. Try adding `http://localhost` only.

Comment: Do you have an idea how I can find out the IP used when running the APK ? I have the same issue, my siteUrl was `http://localhost` only from the beggining. Works fine on browser but not with the apk. Thanks